# LINQ: Filtering items List by some condition and do something with item by condition

Tags: c#, .net, linq, filtering

Assume I have `users` which is `List<User>`, and `User` class has `Type` and `Age` properties.
I want to filter that list of users by some condition, and do something per item, based on condition. Let this list has 10 users, and some of them are of Type `"complex"` and some of them `"simple`". I want my final list to be users with age above 30, and if Type of user is "complex", to do something on it and then add it to final list. It should be something like:

```
var users= users.Where(u => u.Age > 30 
and if u.Type = "complex" ? u = doSomething(u)).ToList();
```

and if `doSomething(u)` returns null, skip current "u" to be added to list.

It is half correct code and half like pseudo code because I don't know how to fit `if u.Type = "complex" ? u = doSomething(u)` part into LINQ expression. How can it be done?

EDIT: And how to do it if I want in final lsit users with Age > 30 OR users with Type = "complex" (and doSomething()) on complex users?

Comment: so you want to have `Age > 30 OR users with Type = "complex" ` or `Age > 30 AND users with Type = "complex" `?

Answer (score 3):

```
var users = users.Where(u => u.Age > 30) // common filter
                 .Select(u => u.Type == "complex" ? doSomething(u) : u) //select user or transformed
                 .Where(u => u != null) //not null only
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: You can go even further and hide the condition 'type == complex'  inside the function and name the function alike to make it even more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something as follow :

```
users.Where(u => u.Age > 30).Select((u) =>
{
    if (u.Type == "complex")
    {
        // Do something
    }

    return u;
}).ToList();
```

Select all users with age > 30 and then altering the result depending on the type property.

EDIT :
And for your Edit question just add the condition to the where :

```
[...].Where(u => u.Age > 30 || u.Type == "complex")[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I came up with some sick variant...

```
public bool DoSomething()
{
    // Do anything
    return true;
}    

var v = users.Where(x => x!= null && x.Age > 30 && x.Type == "Complex" && x.DoSomething() == true).ToList();
```

For your edit:

```
var v = users.Where(x => x!= null && (x.Age > 30 || x.Type == "Complex") && x.DoSomething() == true).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

AND QUERY

```
var andList = users.Where(u => u.Age > 30 && (u.Type == "complex" && doSomething(u) != null)).ToList();
```

OR QUERY

```
var orList = users.Where(u => u.Age > 30 || (u.Type == "complex" && doSomething(u) != null)).ToList();
```